# Javascript can't read my json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

So I took some data from my database and placed it in a json array using the following code:

getDataFromDB:

```
<?php

include"connectToDB.php";
//voert de volgende query uit
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM youtubevideos");

$array = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array = $row;
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

dataToHTML.js:

```
$.getJSON("getDataFromDB.php", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        console.log(field);
    });
});
```

In the console.log(field) it's supposed to give me all the data from the array. But for some reason my console is empty. It seems like it can't read my array. But the funny thing is... 
When I type `exit();` after this line of code `echo json_encode($array);` in my php file it somehow can read it. But the problem is is that it only gives me a single row from my database. Ofcourse I want to get all the data from my database, so I can't use `exit();`. Are their any other suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: in the php portion why aren't you adding elements to the array, right now your setting the array to row, change to `$array[] = $row` to push a row into the array, then move the echo to after the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php file is returning multiple `json` strings, because you `echo` inside the `for` loop.

Change your code to this

```
<?php

include"connectToDB.php";
//voert de volgende query uit
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM youtubevideos");

$array = array(); // you can remove this

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

You will get all rows now.

Comment: you dont need this line : `$array = array();`

Comment: @CodeGodie you are correct, I added it as a comment to match your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is outputting an JSON array on every row returned by your database:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $array = $row;
  echo json_encode($array);
}
```

You should add items to and array first then output your json encoded array outside the loop.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Try that.